# How to mitigate host + device memory tranfer bottlenecks in OpenCL/CUDA

Tags: memory, cuda, opencl, nvidia

If my algorithm is bottlenecked by host to device and device to host memory transfers, is the only solution a different or revised algorithm?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are a couple things you can try to mitigate the PCIe bottleneck:

- Asynchronous transfers - permits overlapping computation and bulk transfer
- Mapped memory - allows a kernel to stream data to/from the GPU during execution

Note that neither of these techniques makes the transfer go faster, they just reduce the time the GPU is waiting on the data to arrive.

With the `cudaMemcpyAsync` API function you can initiate a transfer, launch one or more kernels that **do not depend** on the result of the transfer, synchronize the host and device, and then launch kernels that were waiting on the transfer to complete.  If you can structure your algorithm such that you're doing productive work while the transfer is taking place, then asynchronous copies are a good solution.

With the `cudaHostAlloc` API function you can allocate host memory that can read and written directly from the GPU.  The reason this is faster is that a block that needs host data only needs to wait for a  **small portion** of the data to be transferred.  In contrast, the usual approach makes all blocks wait until the **entire** transfer is complete.  Mapped memory essentially breaks a big monolithic transfer into a bunch or smaller copy operations, so the latency is reduced.

You can read more about these topics in Section 3.2.6-3.2.7 of the [CUDA Programming Guide](http://developer.download.nvidia.com/compute/cuda/3_2/toolkit/docs/CUDA_C_Programming_Guide.pdf) and Section 3.1 of the [CUDA Best Practices Guide](http://developer.download.nvidia.com/compute/cuda/3_2/toolkit/docs/CUDA_C_Best_Practices_Guide.pdf).  Chapter 3 of the [OpenCL Best Practices Guide](http://developer.download.nvidia.com/compute/cuda/3_2/toolkit/docs/OpenCL_Best_Practices_Guide.pdf) explains how to use these features in OpenCL.

Comment: Are those two techniques available in OpenCL?

Comment: Yes, they're discussed in Chapter 3 of the OpenCL Best Practices Guide.  I've updated my answer with a link.

Answer (score 3):

You really need to do the math to be certain that you're going to be doing enough processing on the GPU to make it worthwhile transferring data between host and GPU. Ideally you do this at the design stage, before doing any coding, since it can be a deal-breaker.